# Not getting success callback after FTP upload

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an worklight based app for ipad in which i have to send the response to java script after successful FTP file upload using CDVPlugin.  Initially i am calling the making the call to ios from java script to the following mention function.

```
- (void)sendFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
      ...
      ...
      callbackId = command.callbackId;
      self.callbackId = command.callbackId;
      NSLog(@"callback ID Top %@",callbackId);
}
```

When the task is finished i am sending the status back to javascript using the following code.

// last call after completion:

```
- (void) returnSuccess {
      NSMutableDictionary* posError = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
      [posError setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: CDVCommandStatus_OK] forKey:@"code"];
      [posError setObject: @"Success" forKey: @"message"];
      CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:posError];

       //[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];
       [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:self.callbackId];
       NSLog(@"result ==>> %@",result);
       NSLog(@"callbackId down ==>> %@",callbackId);
}
```

but my problem is that i am not receiving anything in javascript. When i debugged the code the control went to all the lines and also printing all the nslog lines(FtpUpload575396340) still response is not sent to javascript.

can please anyone help and tell me what can be wrong in this?

JAVASCRIPT CODE :

```
function upload(){
var args = {};
args.address = " ";
args.username = " ";
args.password = "  "; 
cordova.exec(successCallback, failCallback, "FtpUpload", "sendFile", [args]);  
}



function successCallback(data){
//busyInd.hide();
var dialogSuccessTitle = "Success";
var dialogSuccessText =data.message; 
WL.SimpleDialog.show(dialogSuccessTitle, dialogSuccessText, 
    [{ text:'OK' },{ text:'Cancel' }  ]); 
// $('#show_button').show();
document.getElementById("show_button").disabled=false;
console.log('successCallback' + JSON.stringify(data));


}



function failCallback(data){
//busyInd.hide();
var dialogErrorTitle = "Warning"; 
var dialogErrorText = data.message;  
WL.SimpleDialog.show(dialogErrorTitle, dialogErrorText, 
    [{ text:'OK' },{ text:'Cancel' } ]);
//$('#show_button').show();
document.getElementById("show_button").disabled=false;
console.log('failCallback' + JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: So maybe the problem is in the JavaScrip. Add the JS code that receives the data from the plug-in.

Comment: I posted the JavaScript code.i did same approach for ftp download and that is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not getting success callback because every time after upload operation my "self.commandDelegate" was getting null.
So i am explaining my approach here
I added

```
CDVPlugin *handler;
@implementation FtpUpload
{
uint8_t                     _buffer[kSendBufferSize];
}
```

on top and in first method i did like that

```
- (void)sendFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command { 
callbackId = command.callbackId;
self.callbackId = command.callbackId; 
handler = self; 
}
```

then in return success

```
- (void) returnSuccess {

NSMutableDictionary* posError = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
[posError setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: CDVCommandStatus_OK] forKey:@"code"];
[posError setObject: @"Success" forKey: @"message"];
CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:posError];  
[handler.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];


}
```

So my problem is solved now.